# Entity having one of multiple parents, which are different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a C# EF MVC project in combination with a MySql database and I am trying to setup my database schema through a code-first approach (with migrations enabled).
For my example I have simplified my model down to the 3 classes shown below:

```cs
public class Message
{
  [Key]
  public int MessageId { get; set; }
  // Some properties ...

  // There will always be one filled in and not the other
  public virtual CorrectedContent CorrectedContent { get; set; }
  public virtual MessageContent MessageContent { get; set; }
}

public class CorrectedContent
{
  [Key]
  public int CorrectedContentId { get; set; }

  public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
  // ...
  public MessageContent MessageContent { get; set; }  // Nullable
}

public class MessageContent
{
  [Key]
  public int MessageContentId { get; set; }

  public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
  public virtual CorrectedContent CorrectedContent
  // ...
}
```

To make sure the relations were mapped properly I also used the EF Fluent Api on my DbContext.

```cs
public class TestContext: DbContext
{
  public TestContext(): base("TestContext") { }
  // My DbSets and such ...

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<CorrectedContent>()
      .HasOptional(x => x.MessageContent)
      .WithRequired(y => y.CorrectedContent)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
      .HasOptional(x => x.MessageContent)
      .WithRequired(y => y.Message)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
      .HasOptional(x => x.CorrectedContent)
      .WithRequired(y => y.Message)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
  }
}
```

The issue I have is when I try to add a `Message` with `MessageContent` to my database I get:

> Cannot add or update child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ("DbName"."MessageContent", CONSTRAINS
>   "FK_MessageContent_CorrectedContent_MessageContentId " FOREIGN KEY
>   ("MessageContentId ") REFERENCES "CorrectedContent"
>   ("CorrectedContentId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I have tried putting both entities on "withOptional" but that didn't work, I also tried working with a mutual interface for both the `Message` and `CorrectedContent`.

So the `Message`should have a one-to-one-or-zero relationship to `MessageContent`, `CorrectedContent` also has a one-to-one-or-zero relationship with `MessageContent` and `Message` has a one-to-one-or-zero with `CorrectedContent`.

Comment: You specificed that `MessageContent` _requires_ a `CorrectedContent` too, thus you have to provide a `CorrectedContent` to the `MessageContent` your `Message` carries.

Comment: You should also show the code that tries to add the `Message` because it may matter what you do exactly.

Comment: @StackLloyd yes because either `CorrectedContent` or `Message`should be declared (not both), is there a way to ensure I have one or the other?

Comment: @GertArnold I use a simple `db.Message.add(MessageInstance)` and `db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: AFAIK, no. When you use `WithRequired`, a `NOT NULL` constraint is applied to the corresponding column, which means both of your columns _must_ have a value. However, of course, if you disable it, they can both be `NULL`. Either you provide a default, "dummy" value to the other entity (first option), or you write code which ensures either of the two has a value (second option).

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936075/how-use-reflection-to-condition-multiple-properties-to-check-for-equality-in-a-l) which looks exactly like what you're stuck on. Unfortunately, it seems MySQL doesn't support proper code for such a feat and you have to rely on a trigger. I don't think EF can help you here.

Comment: If you only add a `Message` there can't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**My current solution:**

Because the XSD (and send in xml files) where my data would come from was too complicated to transform into a proper database model I opted for a less than ideal solution where I only have 2 classes like shown below.

```cs
public class Message
{
  [Key]
  public int MessageId { get; set; }
  // Some properties ...

  public virtual MessageContent MessageContent { get; set; }
}

public class MessageContent
{
  [Key]
  public int MessageContentId { get; set; }

  public virtual Message Message { get; set; }

  [Required, Column(TypeName = "text")]
  public string XMLString { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public MessageType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum MessageType
{
  Correction,
  Normal,
  // more options ...
}
```

In the model I only open the first element of a received XML which is always of type `Message`. Then I look for the child element and get its type which is `MessageType`. The `XMLString` property contains this child in `string` representation.

I know this is a bad designed solution but it works for my application just fine. I use the XSD (classes) that was provided to my on my front-end so I only have to parse the XMLString to the XSD classes.

Any better solutions are always welcome.